# Neo4j docker configuration file overwrites original supplied configuration file in volume

Tags: docker, neo4j

In order to test py2neo functions in a docker environment, I have attempted to create a jupyter notebook container alongside a Neo4j container. For the Neo4j container I am using the official Neo4j image off dockerhub.

The relevant bits of my docker-compose.yml file are as follows:

```
version: '2'  

services:  

  neo4j:  
    image: neo4j  
    container_name: neo4j  
    ports:  
      - "7474:7474"  
      - "7687:7687"  
    volumes:  
      - ./neo4j/data:/data  
      - ./n4j_conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf  
      - ./neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import  
      - ./n4j_plugins:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins  
    networks:
- elk
```

(I added the n4j_conf directory under the main project directory to bind the configuration volume due to neo4j not being able to run if I bound the volume directly to the neo4j/conf directory.)

Previously, I have read that I need to change this line in the neo4j.conf file:

> dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

Before activating the neo4j container, I ensure the configuration file I supply in the localhost is correct, but after I activate my containers with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

That particular line I wanted to un-comment is completely gone, but the other bits I added for using algorithms are still there.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

3 of your volume container paths seem to be wrong. Try deleting `/var/lib/neo4j` from them.

Comment: Hmm.... I gave it a try. While the configuration file still retains the settings for algorithms I added, the setting  
  
**dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0**   
  
and the setting that allows LOAD CSV still become missing.

On the other hand, interacting with the container through  
**docker exec -it c2f bash**
doesn't overwrite the configuration on my local side anymore....
  
Also, my import volume doesn't bind correctly anymore...

Comment: **I found the correct configuration file and import folder.. it's located under the root directory of the container, not the neo4j directory, would that be as intended?**

Comment: Yes, that is what is documented.